# Create a Datagrid Style/CustomControl with rounded corners in WPF

Tags: wpf, templates, datagrid, styles

I would like to spice up my WPF GUI a bit by adding datagrids with rounded corners.
I found an article that described nicely how it's done when you apply it directly to one specific datagrid. It works like this:

```
 <Border CornerRadius="10" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="10" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" >
                <Border.BitmapEffect>
                    <DropShadowBitmapEffect></DropShadowBitmapEffect>
                </Border.BitmapEffect>
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="BDRounded" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="White" CornerRadius="10"></Border>
                    <DataGrid x:Name="AKGrid"  Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding List}"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" IsReadOnly="True" >
                        <DataGrid.OpacityMask>
                            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=BDRounded}"></VisualBrush>
                        </DataGrid.OpacityMask>
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="50" Binding="{Binding intID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="250" Binding="{Binding txtDescription}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
```

I now want to encapsulate that into a style or a custom control. My questions are:
What would be the best way to go in this case? CustomControl, UserControl, Style or something different? And how would I go about doing that?
It's important that I have a reusable CustomDataGrid that looks like the one above and that I can set all the Headers and Bindings in XAML the way I can with any old datagrid.
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to alter the default look of a WPF control is to provide a new `ControlTemplate` for the relevant control. The best way to provide a new `ControlTemplate` for a control is to start with the default one... for the `DataGrid` control, you can find the default `ControlTemplate` in the [DataGrid Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff506248.aspx) page on MSDN.

If you are not sure how to use a non default `ControlTemplate`, you can find out more from the [`ControlTemplate` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN, but in short, you define a `ControlTemplate` in some `Resources` section and then set it as the value for the control's `Template` property. You can also find further helpful information in the [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

In your case, your surrounding `Border` and `DropShadowBitmapEffect` should be *inside* your new `ControlTemplate`.

Finally, if you want your new `ControlTemplate` to be automatically applied to every `DataGrid` in your application, then do *not* set the `x:Key` directive on the `ControlTemplate` in `Resources`. Otherwise, set the `x:Key` directive on the `ControlTemplate` and then set that value as the `DataGrid.Template` property of the `DataGrid`s that you want to have this look.

Comment: So is there an "easy" way to create a ControlTemplate, where I have basically just these few lines I have given above with one XAML placeholder element such as <ContentPresenter/>, which then automatically places the datagrid I apply the ControlTemplate to there?

Comment: Yes, you can put whatever you like into a `ControlTemplate` as long as you bear in mind that some controls from the default `ControlTemplate`s are required... they are all specified in the relevant page on MSDN and are named `PART_...` so you can see them easily. The `ContentPresenter` is also essential for controls that use it.